# Error using phpMailer and isHTML

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Im using phpMailer to send an image like attachment and a message in HTML. But the page show me that is not working.

```
include 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From      = 'someone@some.com';
$mail->FromName  = 'someone';

$mail->AddAddress( 'someone@some2.com' );
$mail->Subject   = 'Message Subject';

$mail->Body      = "<h1>Test 1 of PHPMailer html</h1><p>This is a test</p>";
$mail->AltBody="This is text only alternative body.";
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$file_to_attach = '../images/logo.png';
$mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'logo.png"' );
if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
else
    echo "Letter is sent";
```

Using this code works perfectly to me send a message with HTML and an attachment.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
$mail->AddAddress('someone@some.com', 'a name');
$mail->SetFrom('someone2@some2.com', 'another name');

$mail->AddReplyTo('someone3@some3.com', 'another name');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test';
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body      = "<h1>Test 1 of PHPMailer html</h1><p>This is a test</p>";
$mail->AddAttachment('../images/logo.png');
$mail->Send(); echo "Message Sent OK\n";
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: You should give absolute path like `http://www.example.com/images/logo.png`. Are getting any error ..?

Comment: That's not an absolute path, it's an absolute URL, and it won't work. `addAttachment` does not support using URLs: `addStringAttachment` can be used for that. There's nothing wrong with using relative paths to attach files, so long as you're sure where your cwd is.

Comment: You should base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer. You've used an obsolete example and are using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: The attachment works fine. The only thing that doesn't works is the message like html. Using this "absolute URL" i can send emails in HTML with the native function of PHP, mail()

Comment: @Synchro Im using the last librery of PHPMailer.  Can you help me with a recent example sending a HTML message and an attachment, please?

Comment: Um, the one in the README file does that? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

You are using $email variable to new object PHPMailer but in line 8,9 and 14,15 you're using $mail.

`$mail->AltBody="This is text only alternative body.";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;`

just use $email.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake. I corrected that, but the error persists.

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using

```
$file_to_attach = '../images/logo.png';
```

to get the name for the image file. However the file name is already set in:

```
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'logo.png"' );
```

Try putting the whole path in `$email->AddAttachment();` like this `$email->AddAttachment('../images/Logo.pgn');`

Comment: It's common to use different names for the source file and the name of the attachment, and that's all this is doing. It doesn't try to attach the same file twice or join the two to make the path, so what you're suggesting makes no difference.